# Understand spring security authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

In spring security I don't understand how does the authentication work. In documentation they have this code

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") 1
            .permitAll();        2
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

In above, how does `.anyRequest().authenticated()` works? In spring, does it automatically authenticate users?

Is it like, this line `.anyRequest().authenticated()` call `configureGlobal` and authenticate with user and password? Usually user and password is saved in database? Then How can I do check authentication for user whose username and password is saved in User table?

Comment: check this...authenticate and assign the roles...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397933/spring-security-role-string/37404402#37404402

Answer (score 0):

> In above, how does .anyRequest().authenticated() works? In spring, does it automatically authenticate users?

`HttpSecurity` creates a security filter chain, and the filters that will be in that chain are added via configurers that are applied to `HttpSecurity`. When you do

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    …
```

you are adding an `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer` that will be used to create a `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, which is a filter that will decide if the current user meets the requirements to obtain access to the resource. In your case, the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` will make sure the user is authenticated (not with an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`) for every request.

The `FilterSecurityInterceptor`’s main job isn’t to authenticate. It expects an `Authentication` to be in the SecurityContextHolder already. It’ll throw an exception otherwise.

> Is it like, this line .anyRequest().authenticated() call configureGlobal and authenticate with user and password? Usually user and password is saved in database? Then How can I do check authentication for user whose username and password is saved in User table?

The authentication is actually going on here:

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login") 1
    .permitAll();
```

The `FormLoginConfigurer` adds a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to the chain that will by default responds to "/login".
Side note: If you look at `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which is the class you’ll usually extend from to get some sensible defaults, you’ll see that certain configurers and thus filters, are applied to HttpSecurity by default.

The `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` you `@Autowired` will be used to create an `AuthenticationManager` that is then shared with several filters including `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to perform authentication. The filter extracts the `"username"` and `"password"` parameters from the `HttpServletRequest`, stores these in a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, and passes it to the `AuthenticationManager`.

Instead of

```
auth
    .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
```

you could try:

```
auth
    .jbdcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        //.other methods to configure UserDetailsService default
```

;

Take a look at the [`JdbcUserDetailsManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.java) (which is the default `UserDetailsService`) to see what SQL commands are executed and what row names it expects to find in your `users` table when authenticating.